# Check whether jar has been called by a JNLP file / Java Web Start

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a JAR file which may be called manually or by Java Web Start / a JNLP file. Is there a possibility to check in the main method, how the JAR has been called?

Comment: Why does your program need to know?

Comment: I would like to do something "special" when it is called by a JNLP file...

Comment: Use a property, and don't set it in the JNLP-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways.  The app. was launched directly via. Jar. if:

1. Add a property to the JNLP file, then check for it in `main()`.  It will be `null`.
2. Check for the existence of the [JNLP API services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).  It is not possible to instantiate them in the normal way.

Comment: I wanted to avoid adding another property in the JNLP file, although this would be a possible solution.
Could you give me a short hint how I can check the existence of the JNLP API service?

Comment: Yes I did... Well... If `ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService")` throws an UnavailableServiceException, the file has not been called by a JNLP, is that right?